# Set imageView width and height programatically raise an exception

Tags: android, imageview, height, width

I'm trying to set image programatically ,but when i set it's size :widht and height it raises an exception.

**PS :Im using ImageLayout Library**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       imageLayout = (ImageLayout)findViewById(R.id.image_layout);

   ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
   image.setImageResource(R.drawable.positioning);
   ImageLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = new ImageLayout.LayoutParams(); 
   image.requestLayout();
   image.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
   image.getLayoutParams().width = 100;
    layoutParams2.left = 243;
    layoutParams2.top = 297;
    layoutParams2.right = 432;
    layoutParams2.bottom = 405;
    imageLayout.addView(image, layoutParams2);
 }
```

The XML Layou t:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.manuelpeinado.imagelayout.ImageLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/image_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#aaa"
    custom:fit="both"
    custom:image="@drawable/boroughs2"
    custom:imageHeight="1744"
    custom:imageWidth="1150" >

  <Button android:id="@+id/manhattan" 
      style="@style/ImageText" 
      custom:layout_centerX="608" 
      custom:layout_centerY="595" 
      android:text="@string/manhattan" 
      android:onClick="onButtonClick" />

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/red" 
      custom:layout_centerX="160" 
      custom:layout_centerY="200" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/router1"
      style="@style/ImageText.Normal"
      custom:layout_centerX="160"
      custom:layout_centerY="64"
      custom:layout_maxWidth="440"
      android:text="Router 1"
      android:textColor="#FF0000" />

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/red" 
      custom:layout_centerX="1000" 
      custom:layout_centerY="640" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/router2"
      style="@style/ImageText.Normal"
      custom:layout_centerX="1000"
      custom:layout_centerY="500"
      custom:layout_maxWidth="440"
      android:text="Router 2"
      android:textColor="#FF0000" />


  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/red" 
      custom:layout_centerX="300" 
      custom:layout_centerY="1500" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/router3"
      style="@style/ImageText.Normal"
      custom:layout_centerX="300"
      custom:layout_centerY="1400"
      custom:layout_maxWidth="440"
      android:text="Router 3"
      android:textColor="#FF0000" />

  </com.manuelpeinado.imagelayout.ImageLayout>
   </HorizontalScrollView>
```

The LogCat (Line 25 : image.getLayoutParams().height = 100; )

```
    05-22 10:57:26.206: W/asset(30765): AssetManager-->addDefaultAssets CIP path not exsit!
05-22 10:57:27.190: I/dalvikvm-heap(30765): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.201MB for 4515232-byte allocation
05-22 10:57:27.809: I/dalvikvm-heap(30765): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.112MB for 2005616-byte allocation
05-22 10:57:27.971: W/dalvikvm(30765): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40cb39a8)
05-22 10:57:27.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30765): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-22 10:57:27.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30765): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.drawdraw/com.example.drawdraw.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-22 10:57:27.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30765):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
05-22 10:57:27.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30765):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
05-22 10:57:27.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30765):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
05-22 10:57:27.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30765):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
05-22 10:57:27.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30765):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
05-22 10:57:27.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30765):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
05-22 10:57:27.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30765):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
05-22 10:57:27.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30765):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 10:57:27.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30765):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-22 10:57:27.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30765):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
05-22 10:57:27.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30765):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
05-22 10:57:27.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30765):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-22 10:57:27.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30765): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-22 10:57:27.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30765):    at com.example.drawdraw.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
05-22 10:57:27.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30765):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
05-22 10:57:27.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30765):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
05-22 10:57:27.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30765):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
05-22 10:57:27.987: E/AndroidRuntime(30765):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a NPE because the view has not been drawn yet and there are no layout params associated with it. You should first draw the layout and then only you should get layout params.

Comment: Thank you for replying. But how can i draw the layout first, using that code ? @Ajit Pratap Singh